# Highcharts area color negative value but no color positive value

Tags: highcharts, colors, area

I'm using highchart with area I want no color for positive value area but a color for negative area value.
Check link for image.
Is it possible?
Thanks
series: [{
type: 'areaspline',
data: [
0, 55440.0, 111560.04833, 112339.71916, 112472.46654, 112517.60124, 112304.13865, 112164.4945,
112126.68508, 100603.11168, -21269.6799, -21293.85952, -21433.65793, -21443.22706,
-21536.02614, -21570.02976, -17035.60628, -12398.79965, -12501.13564, -12546.36009,
-12680.17631, -12785.62897, -12872.93642, -13005.94782, -13120.47298, -6560.55385,
],
name: 'Test',
negativeFillColor: '#0088FF',
marker: {
enabled: true,
symbol: 'circle',
fillColor: '#559BD1',
},
dataLabels: {
enabled: false,
},
}],

Answer (score 0):

Use `series.zones` option, to set `fillColor` for specific ranges.

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.zones

```
  plotOptions: {
    areaspline: {
      zoneAxis: 'y',
      zones: [{
        value: 0,
        fillColor: colors[0]
      }, {
        value: Infinity,
        fillColor: 'transparent'
      }]
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b8jwvtz0/